# How should I name my "music" folder containing sheet music/tabs/compositions/lessons?

Tags: terminology, computer

(Sorry if this is too subjective or off-topic, but I've been struggling with this minor issue for too long)

Like most musicians, I listen to music and work on music. On my computer, I have a folder with many music albums that I listen to, and another folder containing sheet music, tabs, and well as lessons or compositions.

I fail to find an appropriate name for this second folder, that would encompass the practice, teaching and composition aspects. Do you have a good name for it? Or do you maybe split these different aspects in different folders?

Comment: Charts and dots? Or Orchs which is what all the charts together for a piece is sometimes called?

Comment: @Tim It's true that most of the content in this folder will be sheet music or tabs, but there is also video/audio files, as well as lyrics for example. I like the originality of  your suggestions though :)

Comment: For the record, after some time using "OwnMusic" (which wasn’t satisfying at all), I finally settled on the simple "MusicStuff." I thought I should share that just in case!

Answer (score 1):

- For music I listen to: Muzak
- For music I write: Music
- For music I record: Recordings
- For writing: Documents
- For useful things: Composition Resources

Label appropriate sub folders for each of these categories and boom, you’ve got organization.

Incidentally, every file is named with the file name, draft number, and date:

Obnoxious Piece (Draft #14) - May 54th, 2034

Keeps everything straight.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the insight into your folder organization! So you keep in separate folders the music you write and your own recordings of the same music?

Comment: Yes, they’re not the same as I’m often dealing with the difference between notated music and raw audio.